# Merging Second Row number if exists to column 2 or column 3 of first row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
CustNO VARCHAR (50),    
RelationNo VARCHAR (50),    
POSTCODE VARCHAR (50),
PHONE001 VARCHAR (50),  
PHONE002 VARCHAR (50),  
PHONE003 VARCHAR (50)
)
INSERT @TABLE

SELECT 'A0002023','N195UN','121408',    '02075614860','','' UNION ALL   
SELECT 'A0002023','N195UN','121408',    '0207561860','',''  UNION ALL
SELECT 'E3085141','15252','408121', '5566456',  '', ''  UNION ALL
SELECT 'E3085141','15252','408121', '256756616',    '', ''  UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZBT5489','88888','555555',  '6665589',  '', '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'JEZTSUR1','9999','558121',  '9986141',  '', ''  UNION ALL
SELECT 'JEZTSUR1','9999','558121',  '963283',   '', ''  UNION ALL
SELECT 'JEZTSUR1','9999','558121',  '679971',   '', ''
```

When CustNo, RelationNo and PhoneNumber match than try to merge Phone number of

second line merge to second or third phone number of first line.

Output

```
 CustNO   |  Relationnumber|phone001| phone002|phone003
    A0002023|   N195UN| 121408| 02075614860|0207561860|''   
    E3085141|   15252|  408121| 5566456|256756616|''    
    ZBT5489 |    88888| 555555| 6665589|''|''   
    JEZTSUR1|   9999|   558121| 9986141|963283| 679971
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
        SELECT distinct
              m.CustNO
            , m.RelationNo
            , m.POSTCODE
            , PHONE001 = STUFF((
                  SELECT ',' + md.PHONE001
                  FROM dbo.@TABLE md
                  WHERE m.CustNO = md.CustNO and m.RelationNo = md.RelationNo and m.POSTCODE = md.POSTCODE 
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
        FROM dbo.@TABLE m
```

> OutPut :

[image]

Comment: Sorry: Mr Bhosale: my problem is i don't want all the values in single column, if value  has to be in next column

Comment: May Someone please help me. :)